# How does PostgreSQL stores DateTime with no timezone

Tags: c#, postgresql, date, datetime, psql

I am new to PostgreSQL database and not sure how the DateTime without time zone is stored. I am trying to retrieve the fields in my c# and not sure what is the format specifier of a DateTime without time zone of a psql field in c#. I see two different formats for the same data type

[image]

Can I give yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff as format specifier for both the fields in c#.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, as datetime fields in databases aren't (usually) stored as strings, so they don't have any associated "format".  What are you wanting to actually know?

Comment: @MattJohnson I am connecting to PostgreSQL from BizTalk so I am trying to access those fields in BizTalk schemas

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL's `timestamp without time zone` does take the `2017-03-20 15:45:00` format with [resolution down to sub-millisecond](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html).  As to mapping to .NET's native data type, you might want to take a look at [this](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html).